# Pimcore installation - ajax calls from install.php 403 forbidden

Tags: php, installation, http-status-code-403, pimcore

I am trying to install pimcore 5 with php 7.

When i enter the data to the install form (db name, user, pass.. etc) and press check requirements or install two different ajax post calls happen. When i get the result from both post calls i get 403 forbidden error, ther response is only "Forbidden".

Don't know what to change, and what caused the error. 
My server has php 7.1, all the minimum requirements are sufficient.

Please help, regards Dejan

Comment: Your apache/nginx configuration is wrong. Check: https://pimcore.com/docs/5.0.x/Development_Documentation/Installation_and_Upgrade/System_Setup_and_Hosting/Nginx_Configuration.html

Comment: Tnx! My host is using apache. What shoul configurations be?! I have no clue! I met min requirements. Phpinfo is available at kropec.eu. I dont find any special settings at pimcore docu for apache https://pimcore.com/docs/5.0.x/Development_Documentation/Installation_and_Upgrade/System_Setup_and_Hosting/Apache_Configuration.html. Can somebody help an see phpinfo...?

Comment: Show me your config file from /etc/apache2/site-enabled/your-config-file.conf and your .htaccess from projetct-root/web

Answer (score 0):

Thats conf file.

```
<VirtualHost 91.185.211.24:80 >
     ServerName www.tmp.kropec.eu
     ServerAlias www.tmp.kropec.eu tmp.kropec.eu
     ServerAdmin webmaster@kropec.eu
     DocumentRoot /home/ropc01/domains/kropec.eu/public_html/tmp
     UseCanonicalName OFF
     <IfModule !mod_ruid2.c>
             SuexecUserGroup ropc01 ropc01
     </IfModule>
     CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/kropec.eu.tmp.bytes bytes
     CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/kropec.eu.tmp.log combined
     #ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domains/kropec.eu.tmp.error.log
     ErrorLog /dev/null
     <Directory /home/ropc01/domains/kropec.eu/public_html>
             AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Indexes Limit
Options=Indexes,IncludesNOEXEC,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch,FollowSymLinks     ,None
             Options -ExecCGI -Includes +IncludesNOEXEC
             php_admin_flag engine ON
             php_admin_value sendmail_path '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
    -f ropc01@kropec.eu'
             php_admin_value mail.log /home/ropc01/.php/php-mail.log
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Obviusly my host doesn work with tmp subdomains. Sorry i bothered.